# « Trafic » peut-il être utilisé de façon similaire à l'anglais « car traffic » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, transports

> Somewhat surprisingly, and in tribute to its effectiveness, continuum mechanics effectively models car traffic.

Je voudrais rendre en français la phrase ci-dessus. Voici le résultat :

> De manière assez surprenante et en hommage à son efficacité, la mécanique des milieux continus modélise efficacement le trafic automobile.

Je me demande si je peux employer « trafic » et si ce ne serait pas mieux d'employer « circulation (véhiculaire) ».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Votre phrase est correcte et sera comprise mais effectivement, circulation conviendrait mieux pour lever toute ambiguïté avec le trafic "commerce illicite"

Je garderais cependant "circulation automobile", pas "circulation véhiculaire".

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que l'expression consacrée serait plutôt le trafic *routier*, pas le trafic automobile. Comme le dit Laurent, "trafic automobile", ça sonne comme si on parlait de quelque chose d'illégal.

Comment: Bien que « trafic routier » soit le terme courant, il n'y pas une bien forte contre-indication  à l'usage du terme « trafic automobile », qui n'est pas encore « trafic d'automobiles ».